# Android App Checkbox lag when updating

Tags: java, android, eclipse, lag

I am somewhat new to Android app development and I have made a few basic apps. I am currently having some issues with one of my apps in the form of update delay / lag.

Originally my app had a difficulty (seekBar) meter. I setup all the code and tested it on both an emulator and my HTC One Mini. With both tests I had horrible lag with the seek bar. When I dragged it along, it would take a good few seconds to catch up. This left a horribly nasty to use difficulty bar.

I have since scrapped the idea and have changed my app to have a few different check boxes for the difficulty (allowing the user to select more than 1 difficulty). I just tested the check box now and I am having the same issue with the seek bar. I select the checkbox, then it takes a few seconds to turn on, and vice versa. I am not sure if this is a problem with my code, the emulator or some other problem.

Any help would be great, I can post my code / layout if it will help.

Thanks!!

Comment: post the code that is being run in response to seekbar/checkbox interaction

Comment: There is currently no code being executed. The only thing I was doing (before I commented it all out), was when a button is pushed, it retrieves which check boxes are ticked

Answer (score 0):

Android is a multiprocessing environment and this is how you take advantage of that by executing the information in the background. Determine what needs to be set right then and do, such as updating a test view to reflect the value so the user doesn't feel the lag then do heavy lifting in the backend (database, server, other network calls) and finally come back to it and set any final values.

Once the value is set, do this:

```
Long[] params = {your_param, or_params}; // this can be any object
new AsyncTask<Long, Void, Void>(){
    @Override
protected Void doInBackground(Long... params) {
         Long param = params[0];
         // TODO: call whatever you need in the background, database changes, etc.
    }
    @Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
        // TODO: any UI changes that need to be made, or toast shown
        // UI changes cannot be made in background thread, this brings it back to UI thread
    }
}.execute(params);
```

Comment: Hey there, thanks for the help but I am still confused as to how to implement what you are talking about. Also, is this really necessary? My App is very basic, surely I do not need to utilise what you are saying, after all I have no code executing when the check boxes are selecting. If I do need this, any links I could read for further info? Thanks !!

Comment: If you don't have any heavy code executing in the background then that shouldn't happen... is this on the emulator or on a device?

Comment: Just re-read the question and saw you ran it on both. OK, so can you post your code?

Comment: Hey, ok I have found my problem; it is the large resolution background on the app. The picture is really big (1600 x 1080). Obviously this is way too big, but what are the correct background sizes I should provide? I'll also have a Google search. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yeah, Ill let you search that. I dont know off the top of my head but keep in mind its a total StackOverflow faux pas to change the question